# transactional emails and php

Tags: template, url, email-templates

How do i get my outside link (href as well `getTrackNumber()`) to work? Below is a small template for my shipment update email:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="email/header.phtml"}}
<h1 style="font-size:22px; font-weight:normal; line-height:22px; margin:0 0 11px 0;">Dear {{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerName()}},</h1>
<p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 10px 0;">
    Your order # {{var order.increment_id}} has been shipped and now has a status of <strong>{{var order.getStatusLabel()}}</strong>.
</p>
<p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 10px 0;">You can check the status of your order by 

        <a href="https://mystore.narvar.com/mystore/tracking/fedex?tracking_numbers=<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_track->getTrackNumber()) ?>">logging into your account</a>.


<p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 10px 0;">{{var comment}}</p>
<p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 10px 0;">
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_shipment_items" shipment=$shipment order=$order}}
</p>
<p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 10px 0;">
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/order/shipment/track.phtml' shipment=$shipment order=$order}}
</p>
<p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0;">
    If you have any questions, please feel free to contact us at
    <a href="mailto:{{config path='trans_email/ident_support/email'}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;">{{config path='trans_email/ident_support/email'}}</a>
    or by phone at {{config path='general/store_information/phone'}}.
</p>
{{block type="core/template" template="email/footer.phtml"}}
```

Instead of having them "logging into your account" I want them to go straight to that URL.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Below will add tracking number and url,

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/order/shipment/track.phtml' shipment=$shipment order=$order}}
```

Make sure you have got `email/order/shipment/track.phtml` file.

This file should have something like this:

```
<?php $_shipment=$this->getShipment() ?>
<?php $_order=$this->getOrder() ?>
<?php if ($_shipment && $_order && $_shipment->getAllTracks()): ?>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Shipped By') ?></th>
            <th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Tracking Number') ?></th>
            <th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Tracking URL') ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_shipment->getAllTracks() as $_item): $i++ ?>
        <tr <?php echo $i%2?'bgcolor="#F6F6F6"':'' ?>>
            <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getTitle()) ?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getNumber());//getConsignmentNumber()) ?></td>
            <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:3px 9px"><a href="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getTrackUrl());?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getTrackUrl());?></a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I haven't tested, but should work.

**UPDATE**

After looking at your db screenshot, tracking url is not stored in db.

In that case if you want to have tracking url same all the time then you could just add it in your `track.phtml` file like this:

Replace this line:

```
<td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:3px 9px"><a href="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getTrackUrl());?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getTrackUrl());?></a></td>
```

with this:

```
<?php $trackUrl = "http://myurl.com";?>
<td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:3px 9px"><a href="<?php echo $trackUrl. $_item->getNumber();?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $trackUrl. $_item->getNumber();?></a></td>
```

Comment: This should take them to a different website: https://mystore.narvar.com/mystore/tracking/fedex?tracking_numbers=<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_track->getTrackNumber()) ?>">logging into your account</a>

Comment: Is tracking url and number stored in your database? And is it tracking url will be same all the time?

Comment: Yes, in a table called sales_flat_shipment_track and the field is track_number. i'll update original post with an image for visual.

Comment: It's grabbing details from the DB, yes. I'm testing now. @Adarsh Khatri

Comment: Also check my update.

Comment: In my email template what do i put here instead of url="customer/account/"?  <a href="{{store url="customer/account/"}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;">logging into your account</a>.</p>

Comment: that's in system > transactional emails > shipment update

Comment: This is fine, it is just asking customer to login to your site and check order status.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42142/discussion-between-thismethod-and-adarsh-khatri).

Comment: If i have extended popup.phtml and track.phtml in a module how can i get it from the module instead?